# Space between padding and content in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, joomla

I have this website *** and it has a problem.

In Firefox the language switcher thingy stretches and country flags list items get some sort of a gap between padding and content [Imgur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gxn.png)

In chrome and Edge, it works fine.
I tried setting heights everywhere but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `height: 100%;` and `display: block;` to your `img` using css:

```
div.mod-languages img {

    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;

}
```